# Где можно изучить jframe?

Tags: java, jframe

Решил перейти с консольных приложений на десктопные. Но на просторах интернета никак не могу найти ничего внятного о jframe. Подскажите, может есть какой хороший сайт? Или jframe не актуальная библиотека и стоит изучать другую? Jframe подойдёт, если я хочу написать игру?

Comment: Сейчас все переезжают в web для построения бизнес приложений, для игр даже не знаю, что можно посоветовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JFrame** - это часть библиотеки **Swing**. Вы можете почитать официальную документацию (javadoc) по [JFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html), а также почитать [руководства](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) о том как использовать эту библиотеку.

Для простой (в графическом плане) игры вам будет достаточно библиотеки **Swing**.

Answer (score 1):

`JFrame` - это класс в библиотеке [Swing](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing) (библиотека для создания графического интерфейса на `Java`).

Конструктор класса создаёт, по сути, окно с рамкой с кнопками "Свернуть", "Во весь экран" и "Закрыть":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создание игры на `Swing` зависит от сложности игры. Какие-нибудь крестики-нолики можно создать, для создания сложной игры лучше рассмотреть другие инструменты.